# How to get the build UUID in runtime and the image base address

Tags: ios, uuid

Is there away to get the build UUID, the one that you can check in the dSYM generated file and the image base address in iOS.

Not so good when it comes to low level stuff, anyone can enlighten?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a solution similar to Kerni's answer but which works for any platform (iOS device + simulator and OS X) and any architecture (32-bit + 64-bit). It also returns a `NSUUID` instead of a `NSString`.

```
#import <mach-o/dyld.h>
#import <mach-o/loader.h>

static NSUUID *ExecutableUUID(void)
{
    const struct mach_header *executableHeader = NULL;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < _dyld_image_count(); i++)
    {
        const struct mach_header *header = _dyld_get_image_header(i);
        if (header->filetype == MH_EXECUTE)
        {
            executableHeader = header;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!executableHeader)
        return nil;

    BOOL is64bit = executableHeader->magic == MH_MAGIC_64 || executableHeader->magic == MH_CIGAM_64;
    uintptr_t cursor = (uintptr_t)executableHeader + (is64bit ? sizeof(struct mach_header_64) : sizeof(struct mach_header));
    const struct segment_command *segmentCommand = NULL;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < executableHeader->ncmds; i++, cursor += segmentCommand->cmdsize)
    {
        segmentCommand = (struct segment_command *)cursor;
        if (segmentCommand->cmd == LC_UUID)
        {
            const struct uuid_command *uuidCommand = (const struct uuid_command *)segmentCommand;
            return [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDBytes:uuidCommand->uuid];
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your own suggestion is way too complicated.

Check this code from HockeySDK which does the same with just a couple of lines of code: https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-iOS/blob/develop/Classes/BITHockeyBaseManager.m#L136

```
- (NSString *)executableUUID {
  // This now requires the testing of this feature to be done on an actual device, since it returns always empty strings on the simulator
#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
  const uint8_t *command = (const uint8_t *)(&_mh_execute_header + 1);
  for (uint32_t idx = 0; idx < _mh_execute_header.ncmds; ++idx) {
    const struct load_command *load_command = (const struct load_command *)command;
    if (load_command->cmd == LC_UUID) {
      const struct uuid_command *uuid_command = (const struct uuid_command *)command;
      const uint8_t *uuid = uuid_command->uuid;
      return [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
               uuid[0], uuid[1], uuid[2], uuid[3],
               uuid[4], uuid[5], uuid[6], uuid[7],
               uuid[8], uuid[9], uuid[10], uuid[11],
               uuid[12], uuid[13], uuid[14], uuid[15]]
              lowercaseString];
    } else {
      command += load_command->cmdsize;
    }
  }
#endif
  return @"";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with a class I found from some colleagues that they found in plausible labs and refactored to their needs.

Here you can get the build UUID the image base address and the application name.

```
    /**
 * @internal
 *
 * Async-safe binary image list element.
 */
typedef struct bin_image {
    /** The binary image's header address. */
    uintptr_t header;

    /** The binary image's name/path. */
    char *name;

    /** The previous image in the list, or NULL */
    struct bin_image *prev;

    /** The next image in the list, or NULL. */
    struct bin_image *next;
} bin_image_t;

/**
 * @internal
 *
 * Async-safe binary image list. May be used to iterate over the binary images currently
 * available in-process.
 */
typedef struct bs_image_list {
    /** The lock used by writers. No lock is required for readers. */
    OSSpinLock write_lock;

    /** The head of the list, or NULL if the list is empty. Must only be used to iterate or delete entries. */
    bin_image_t *head;

    /** The tail of the list, or NULL if the list is empty. Must only be used to append new entries. */
    bin_image_t *tail;

    /** The list reference count. No nodes will be deallocated while the count is greater than 0. If the count
     * reaches 0, all nodes in the free list will be deallocated. */
    int32_t refcount;

    /** The node free list. */
    bin_image_t *free;
} bs_image_list_t;

/**
 * @internal
 *
 * Shared dyld image list.
 */
static bs_image_list_t shared_image_list = { 0 };

/**
 * @internal
 *
 * Maintains a linked list of binary images with support for async-safe iteration. Writing may occur concurrently with
 * async-safe reading, but is not async-safe.
 *
 * Atomic compare and swap is used to ensure a consistent view of the list for readers. To simplify implementation, a
 * write mutex is held for all updates; the implementation is not designed for efficiency in the face of contention
 * between readers and writers, and it's assumed that no contention should realistically occur.
 * @{
 */

/**
 * Initialize a new binary image list and issue a memory barrier
 *
 * @param list The list structure to be initialized.
 *
 * @warning This method is not async safe.
 */
static void image_list_init (bs_image_list_t *list) {
    memset(list, 0, sizeof(*list));

    list->write_lock = OS_SPINLOCK_INIT;
}

/**
 * Free any binary image list resources.
 *
 * @warning This method is not async safe.
 */
static void image_list_free (bs_image_list_t *list) {
    bin_image_t *next = list->head;
    while (next != NULL) {
        /* Save the current pointer and fetch the next pointer. */
        bin_image_t *cur = next;
        next = cur->next;

        /* Deallocate the current item. */
        if (cur->name != NULL)
            free(cur->name);
        free(cur);
    }
}

/**
 * Append a new binary image record to @a list.
 *
 * @param list The list to which the image record should be appended.
 * @param header The image's header address.
 * @param name The image's name.
 *
 * @warning This method is not async safe.
 */
static void image_list_append (bs_image_list_t *list, uintptr_t header, const char *name) {
    /* Initialize the new entry. */
    bin_image_t *new = calloc(1, sizeof(bin_image_t));
    new->header = header;
    new->name = strdup(name);

    /* Update the image record and issue a memory barrier to ensure a consistent view. */
    OSMemoryBarrier();

    /* Lock the list from other writers. */
    OSSpinLockLock(&list->write_lock); {

        /* If this is the first entry, initialize the list. */
        if (list->tail == NULL) {

            /* Update the list tail. This need not be done atomically, as tail is never accessed by a lockless reader. */
            list->tail = new;

            /* Atomically update the list head; this will be iterated upon by lockless readers. */
            if (!OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(NULL, new, (void **) (&list->head))) {
                /* Should never occur */
                NSLog(@"An async image head was set with tail == NULL despite holding lock.");
            }
        }

        /* Otherwise, append to the end of the list */
        else {
            /* Atomically slot the new record into place; this may be iterated on by a lockless reader. */
            if (!OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(NULL, new, (void **) (&list->tail->next))) {
                NSLog(@"Failed to append to image list despite holding lock");
            }

            /* Update the prev and tail pointers. This is never accessed without a lock, so no additional barrier
             * is required here. */
            new->prev = list->tail;
            list->tail = new;
        }
    } OSSpinLockUnlock(&list->write_lock);
}

/**
 * Remove a binary image record from @a list.
 *
 * @param header The header address of the record to be removed. The first record matching this address will be removed.
 *
 * @warning This method is not async safe.
 */
static void image_list_remove (bs_image_list_t *list, uintptr_t header) {
    /* Lock the list from other writers. */
    OSSpinLockLock(&list->write_lock); {
        /* Find the record. */
        bin_image_t *item = list->head;
        while (item != NULL) {
            if (item->header == header)
                break;

            item = item->next;
        }

        /* If not found, nothing to do */
        if (item == NULL) {
            OSSpinLockUnlock(&list->write_lock);
            return;
        }

        /*
         * Atomically make the item unreachable by readers.
         *
         * This serves as a synchronization point -- after the CAS, the item is no longer reachable via the list.
         */
        if (item == list->head) {
            if (!OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(item, item->next, (void **) &list->head)) {
                NSLog(@"Failed to remove image list head despite holding lock");
            }
        } else {
            /* There MUST be a non-NULL prev pointer, as this is not HEAD. */
            if (!OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(item, item->next, (void **) &item->prev->next)) {
                NSLog(@"Failed to remove image list item despite holding lock");
            }
        }

        /* Now that the item is unreachable, update the prev/tail pointers. These are never accessed without a lock,
         * and need not be updated atomically. */
        if (item->next != NULL) {
            /* Item is not the tail (otherwise next would be NULL), so simply update the next item's prev pointer. */
            item->next->prev = item->prev;
        } else {
            /* Item is the tail (next is NULL). Simply update the tail record. */
            list->tail = item->prev;
        }

        /* If a reader is active, simply spin until inactive. */
        while (list->refcount > 0) {
        }

        if (item->name != NULL)
            free(item->name);
        free(item);
    } OSSpinLockUnlock(&list->write_lock);
}

/**
 * Retain or release the list for reading. This method is async-safe.
 *
 * This must be issued prior to attempting to iterate the list, and must called again once reads have completed.
 *
 * @param list The list to be be retained or released for reading.
 * @param enable If true, the list will be retained. If false, released.
 */
static void image_list_set_reading (bs_image_list_t *list, bool enable) {
    if (enable) {
        /* Increment and issue a barrier. Once issued, no items will be deallocated while a reference is held. */
        OSAtomicIncrement32Barrier(&list->refcount);
    } else {
        /* Increment and issue a barrier. Once issued, items may again be deallocated. */
        OSAtomicDecrement32Barrier(&list->refcount);
    }
}

/**
 * Return the next image record. This method is async-safe. If no additional images are available, will return NULL;
 *
 * @param list The list to be iterated.
 * @param current The current image record, or NULL to start iteration.
 */
static bin_image_t *image_list_next (bs_image_list_t *list, bin_image_t *current) {
    if (current != NULL)
        return current->next;

    return list->head;
}

/**
 * @internal
 * dyld image add notification callback.
 */
static void image_add_callback (const struct mach_header *mh, intptr_t vmaddr_slide) {
    Dl_info info;

    /* Look up the image info */
    if (dladdr(mh, &info) == 0) {
        NSLog(@"%s: dladdr(%p, ...) failed", __FUNCTION__, mh);
        return;
    }

    /* Register the image */
    image_list_append(&shared_image_list, (uintptr_t) mh, info.dli_fname);
}

/**
 * @internal
 *
 * Write a binary image frame
 *
 * @param file Output file
 * @param name binary image path (or name).
 * @param image_base Mach-O image base.
 */
static void process_binary_image (const char *name, const void *header,
                                    struct uuid_command *out_uuid, uintptr_t *out_baseaddr) {
    uint32_t ncmds;
    const struct mach_header *header32 = (const struct mach_header *) header;
    const struct mach_header_64 *header64 = (const struct mach_header_64 *) header;

    struct load_command *cmd;

    /* Check for 32-bit/64-bit header and extract required values */
    switch (header32->magic) {
            /* 32-bit */
        case MH_MAGIC:
        case MH_CIGAM:
            ncmds = header32->ncmds;
            cmd = (struct load_command *) (header32 + 1);
            break;

            /* 64-bit */
        case MH_MAGIC_64:
        case MH_CIGAM_64:
            ncmds = header64->ncmds;
            cmd = (struct load_command *) (header64 + 1);
            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"Invalid Mach-O header magic value: %x", header32->magic);
            return;
    }

    /* Compute the image size and search for a UUID */
    struct uuid_command *uuid = NULL;

    for (uint32_t i = 0; cmd != NULL && i < ncmds; i++) {
        /* DWARF dSYM UUID */
        if (cmd->cmd == LC_UUID && cmd->cmdsize == sizeof(struct uuid_command))
            uuid = (struct uuid_command *) cmd;

        cmd = (struct load_command *) ((uint8_t *) cmd + cmd->cmdsize);
    }

    /* Base address */
    uintptr_t base_addr;
    base_addr = (uintptr_t) header;

    *out_baseaddr = base_addr;
    if(out_uuid && uuid)
        memcpy(out_uuid, uuid, sizeof(struct uuid_command));
}

+ (void)registerCallback {
    _dyld_register_func_for_add_image(image_add_callback);
}

+ (NSArray *)loadedImages {
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    int i;
    struct uuid_command uuid = { 0 };
    uintptr_t baseaddr;
    char uuidstr[64] = { 0 };

    image_list_set_reading(&shared_image_list, true);

    bin_image_t *image = NULL;
    while ((image = image_list_next(&shared_image_list, image)) != NULL) {

        process_binary_image(image->name, (const void *) (image->header), &uuid, &baseaddr);

        for(i=0; i<16; i++) {
            sprintf(&uuidstr[2*i], "%02x", uuid.uuid[i]);
        }

        [array addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithCString:image->name encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], [NSString stringWithCString:uuidstr encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:(long unsigned) baseaddr], nil]
                                                     forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"uuid", @"baseaddr", nil]]];
    }

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
}
```

You have to call `registerCallbacks` somewhere so that it can properly return results.

Regards.