# Given a mach_header how do I find the binary image name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, dyld, mach

I'm investigating the Mach dynamic linker `dyld`.  This question applies to all Apple platforms but happy for an answer to be platform specific; I'm using ObjC but also happy to translate Swift if that works for you.  [The relevant Apple docs can be found here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/dyld.3.html).

I'm trying to address a deadlocking issue in a library I maintain and so need to capture information about loaded binary images. (for the uninitiated these are not the JPEG kind of images).

I've registered a callback to watch for binary image addition via `_dyld_register_func_for_add_image()` and this is being called as images are loaded.  I can see the `mach_header` structure being passed in as well as the `vmaddr_slide` value.

For various deadlock-avoidance reasons I don't want to iterate over images using `_dyld_image_count()`/`_dyld_get_image_header()` post-hoc, but instead want to keep track of images as they're loaded/unloaded solely using the `add()`/`remove()` callbacks.  Ordinarily I'd be able to call `_dyld_get_image_name(index)` to retrieve an image name as I iterated over images but, like I say, I can't use the iterative model.

My question is: based on the values passed in to the `func_for_add_image()` callback (using any additional system calls necessary) how could I determine the image name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*An* answer, but possibly not *the* answer is the following:

```c
// Required header:
#include <dlfcn.h>

// This is the callback, added via _dyld_register_func_for_add_image()
void add_binary_image(const struct mach_header *header, intptr_t slide)
{
    // ...

    Dl_info  DlInfo;
    dladdr(header, &DlInfo);
    const char* image_name = DlInfo.dli_fname;

    // ...
}
```

[The docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/dladdr.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/dladdr) state that the `dladdr()` function is available only in dynamically linked programs.  The framework I wish to use this in also exists as a static library.  I'm getting to the limits of my knowledge so want to double check that I'm correctly misunderstanding dynamic linking and that using `dladdr()` will be OK in all modern Mac, iOS etc. apps.

[Edit: the `dladdr()` call, above, was fixed with reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19859516/2431627)]

Comment: [You should be fine](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1118/_index.html).