# parsing embedded.mobileprovision and LC_CODE_SIGNATURE to verify the certificate

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate, code-signing-entitlements

My goal is to perform something similar to *[How to get access to iOS Developer Certificate from code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21611575/192373)*: verify that my library is not used in a re-packaged IPA. The answer there suggests to parse the `embedded.mobileprovision` file to see information about the certificates and provisioning profile.

In the `embedded.mobileprovision` file, I can find a long embedded plist, and the XML I see there has two relevant fields:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>AppIDName</key>
…
  <key>application-identifier</key>
  <string>ABCDEFGHIJ.com.example.ObjCExample</string>
…
  <key>UUID</key>
  <string>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</string>
…
  <key>Version</key>
  <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

*(for obvious reasons I replaced the true DEVELOPMENT_TEAM ID with `ABCDEFGHIJ` and the UUID with zeros)*.

There is also a <s>list</s> array of long `<data>` entries under the key `DeveloperCertificates`, but I have no idea how I can use this data. For example, I don't know if I can consistently choose one of these certificates. But I don't see the signing certificate ID in this file, and also I don't have a reliable procedure to parse the `embedded.mobileprovision` file.

Still, this may be enough for my purposes, but I have another, more robust approach. I can parse the `mach_header` of my binary, following the [example](https://davedelong.com/blog/2018/01/10/reading-your-own-entitlements) by [Dave DeLong](https://twitter.com/davedelong) and based on an [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22674561/192373) by [Cédric Luthi](https://twitter.com/0xced). The format of `LC_CODE_SIGNATURE` seems to be better documented than that of the `embedded.mobileprovision` file.

Specifically, the `EMBEDDED_ENTITLEMENTS` blob (magic `0xfade7171`) contains a short plain-text plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>ABCDEFGHIJ.com.example.ObjCExample</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
    <string>ABCDEFGHIJ</string>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <true/>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>ABCDEFGHIJ.com.example.ObjCExample</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

So far so good, but I am not sure how the same XML will look for an app that comes from the AppStore. For example, there is the new `EMBEDDED_ENTITLEMENTS_DER` blob (`0xfade7172`) which seems to hole the same plist, but in binary format (***is there an example that shows how this should be parsed?***).

Also, I see the signing certificate ID `Apple Development: alexcohn@mycompany.com (KLMNOPQRST)` in `REQUIREMENTS` blob (magic `0xfade0c01`), and by following the flow of a [go package](https://github.com/blacktop/go-macho), I can find this ID in my executable programmatically.

***Which certificate ID will be more reliable for my purposes***?

The requirements are simple:

- this ID should change when the app is resigned, even if it is not resigned for the App Store.
- this ID should be present in both debug builds and release builds (these may be different IDs).
- this ID should be *stable*, i.e. it should not change when the developer rebuilds the app, or switches the build machine, or new devices are added to the adHoc provisioning profile.
- this ID should be easy to find (like the signing certificate is visible in the keychain app).

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I found [this repo](https://github.com/elnormous/signature_check) on github, and now I can extract (and verify) the proper SHA256 signature of the signing certificate, which is stored in the standard PKCS7 format in the `0xfade0b01` blob of `LC_CODE_SIGNATURE` command.

The drawback is that I am importing the whole [openssl library](https://teskalabs.com/blog/openssl-binary-distribution-for-developers-static-library) just for that. Isn't there a way to parse this blob with the help of the built-in [SecCertificate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/seccertificate) class? Another open question, maybe embedded openssl lib is more resilient to reverse engineering and Frida-style injection attacks than the system framework?